# Argument values of a Y=F(X) function overlap each other along the X axis

Tags: functions

The plot of a function Y=F(X) shows significant overlaps among the values X takes. X values displayed along the X axis are: 6.15693*10^{-10}, 6.15694*10^{-10}, 6.15695*10^{-10}, etc. and they overlap. Is it possible to make them appear perpendicular to the X axis, so that they will be written parallel to each other and will not overlap? Is there any other solution to my problem? How to prevent coordinates (the values a function's argument takes) from overlapping each other below and along the X axis?

The function I am trying to plot properly looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that the suggestions I have received work when the function is assumed to be a constant, equal to 2.18*10^{-19}. If my function is not a constant, for example if I want to plot the following function:
[image]

The plot appears to be:
[image]

and as you see, coordinates along the horizontal axis are overlapped. Is it possible to prevent coordinate values from overlapping each other along the horizontal axis?

Below is my code:

```
n1[n1a_, fi_] := n1a*Exp[I*fi]
n3[n1a_, fi_, n2_, \[CapitalDelta]_] := n1a*Cos[fi] - 
     ((-n1a^2)*Sin[fi]^2 + n2^2*\[CapitalDelta]^2)^0.5
n4[n1a_, fi_, n2_, \[CapitalDelta]_] := 
 Sin[Re[n1[n1a, fi] - 
     n3[n1a, fi, n2, \[CapitalDelta]]]]/\[CapitalDelta]
nr[\[CapitalDelta]_] := n4[0.0028326, -2, 0.00457, \[CapitalDelta]]
Plot[nr[\[CapitalDelta]], {\[CapitalDelta], 6.156934/10^10, 
  6.156948/10^10}, AxesLabel -> {\[CapitalDelta], nr}]
Clear["Global`*"]
plt = Plot[
  nr[\[CapitalDelta]], {\[CapitalDelta], 6.15694/10^10, 6.15698/10^10}]
xTicks = (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks])[[1]]; 
Show[plt, Ticks -> {xTicks /. str_String :> Rotate[str, Pi/15], 
       Automatic}]
Clear["Global`*"]
plt = Plot[
  nr[\[CapitalDelta]], {\[CapitalDelta], 6.15694*^-10, 6.15698*^-10}]
xTicks = (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks])[[1]]; 
Show[plt, Ticks -> {xTicks /. str_String :> Rotate[str, Pi/15], 
       Automatic}]
```

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code.

Comment: @ cvgmt I am afraid I wouldn't be able to post my entire  Mathematica code as it is to complicated. But you can have an idea about how it looks.

Comment: If the code is too complicated, you should make some effort to create a minimal sample to reproduce the problem, otherwise the question will be off-topic in this site. See: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/1871

Comment: @cvgmt  I have posted a simplified version of my function and the corresponding plot. As you see, Coordinates/numbers along the horizontal axis overlap. Can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

plt = Plot[2.18*^-19, {x, 6.15694*^-10, 6.15698*^-10}]
```

[image]

```
xTicks = (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks])[[1]];
```

[`Rotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rotate.html) the labels until the overlap is removed.

```
Show[plt, Ticks ->
  {xTicks /. str_String :> Rotate[str, Pi/15],
   Automatic}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Another example

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n1[n1a_, fi_] := n1a*Exp[I*fi]
n3[n1a_, fi_, n2_, Δ_] := 
 n1a*Cos[fi] - ((-n1a^2)*Sin[fi]^2 + n2^2*Δ^2)^0.5
n4[n1a_, fi_, n2_, Δ_] := 
 Sin[Re[n1[n1a, fi] - n3[n1a, fi, n2, Δ]]]/Δ
nr[Δ_] := n4[0.0028326, -2, 0.00457, Δ]
plt = Plot[nr[Δ], {Δ, 6.15694/10^10, 6.15698/10^10}];
xTicks = (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[plt, Ticks])[[1]];
Show[plt, Ticks -> 
 {xTicks /. str_String :> Rotate[str, Pi/15], Automatic}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** If your software doesn't support the approach above, don't show the repetitive portion of the tick labels

```
Show[plt, FrameTicks -> {xTicks /. 
    {x_, str_String?(# =!= "" &), r___} :>
     {x, Round[10^15 (x - 6.1569*^-10)], r},
   Automatic},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {StringForm["6.1569_*``", 10^"-10"]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazingly nice. This might solve some of my issues with overlapping vertex labels using `Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, 
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> Rotate["aaaa", Pi/4]}]`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, is it possible to achieve the same result without assuming that my function is taking a constant value (2.18*^-19) within the specified region?

Comment: What have you tried that is not working? Edit your question and include copy and paste-able code (`InputForm`) that demonstrates whatever problem that you are having.

Comment: You have not posted code, but rather a picture of code that cannot be copied and pasted into a notebook. Convert your code to `InputForm` and copy and paste the code. No one wants to re-enter the code working from an image.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon I have posted my code, please have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: The solution is identical to the previous code.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon I am sorry for bothering you again, but after I had your code copied and pasted in my Mathematica, I did not get the numbers rotated. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141319/discussion-between-bob-hanlon-and-neutrino).